# How to show trailing zeroes with float

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

Using SQL Server 2000

zero are not showing while using a float.

Query

```
insert into table1 values ('01.10')
insert into table1 values ('10.50')
insert into table1 values ('02.02')
```

Output

```
Values (datatype is float)

01.1
10.5
02.02
...
```

How to show the last zero's also

Expected Output

Values (datatype is float)

```
01.10
10.50
02.02
...
```

Comment: Why is such formatting not done in your application/front end/reporting layer? This should not have to be done on the Database side.

Comment: Floats don't have trailing zeros, and if they did they would be binary not decimal.

Comment: @EJP you know what he means, though, right? He's talking about trailing zeroes in presentation terms, not in storage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why are you using FLOAT? I find that in a lot of cases people use FLOAT when they don't understand its limitations or peculiarities. For storing decimal values with 2 decimal places, I would use decimal instead.

```
CREATE TABLE #floob(f FLOAT, d DECIMAL(10,2));

INSERT #floob SELECT 2.02, 2.02;
INSERT #floob SELECT 2.7, 2.7;
INSERT #floob SELECT 1.5, 1.5;

SELECT f, f_as_d = CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2), f), d FROM #floob;
```

Results:

```
f        f_as_d   d
------   ------   ------
2.02     2.02     2.02
2.7      2.70     2.70
1.5      1.50     1.50
```

Comment: Hi Aaron, In my case I am displaying a decimal as a character data type and my output is in a excel sheet. I am trying to retain the trailing zero in the decimal using '"' +[Value]+ '"'+'='  But it does not seem to be working. However this is working with leading zeros.

Comment: @Sana this seems to be an Excel display problem, not a programming problem in T-SQL. To maintain trailing zeroes in Excel you'll need to format those cells as the appropriate numeric type.